# Next JS requests for an inexistent JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, next.js

I have created a route "/es/servicios" which is being re-written in `next.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    async redirects() {
        return [
            {
                source: '/',
                destination: '/es',
                permanent: false,
            }
        ]
    },
    async rewrites() {
      return [
        {
            source: '/es/servicios',
            destination: '/es/services',
        },
...
```

When it first loads, it's fine but I don't know why Next JS is trying to load a servcies.json which is causing it to return a 404 error that breaks my site and enters into an infinite loop.

Chrome network inspector tools:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a `getServerSideProps` in your `/es/services` page? If so, what does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

I was returning "not found" to all not matching certain parameters routes in my getServerSideProps and this caused several internal "not founds".